# Symfony :how do you pass an array (result of a query from the database), from the controller to the form and build a drop down menu

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony, choicefield

I have a form and i need to pass it an array. This array is the result of a query from my repository.

I need to build a drop down menu (with a ChoiceType::class, [
'choices' => $array['code']...

Q1: how do you pass the array (to the form from the controller)?

Q2: how do you retrieve the 'code' field and use it in the choices of my form?

Q3: do you have an example for this ?

Tried different things but nothing is working...need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you used so we can help you.

Comment: All the answers of your questions can be found in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: @Harvi Dent: public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $codes = ['code'=>'code10']; //just for a try
        

        //$this->codeChoices = $options['code'];
        $builder
           /*->add('code', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Borrower Id'],            ])
        
            ->add('code', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $codes,
                'choice_label' => 'code',
           ]). Thank you.

Comment: @Lenny4: i read again these Symfony docs and nothing says how to pass an array (result of a querry from the repo) from the controller to the form. If by chance you have this doc then send it over.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49cJK.png)i have found myslef the solution. The Symfony doc is not really helpfull when creating a dynamic customised choice menu (drop down list). I had to use the $options and to dig dip to find the solution. I am happy because the choices are dynamic and they are linked to the Library that is selected when connecting to the site.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1PqH.png)